# Azure Mobile Services LoginAsync() Does not Work (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I've been stuck in authentication problems for a long time now and I've tried everything that was possible to do but I can't find a solution for this problem.

I am using Azure Mobile Services as a backend to my app and everything works perfectly except for the authentication part. 
I am pretty sure I followed every single step of the documentation and revised it again and again.

The error happens after using LoginAsync(): **"Cannot GET /.auth/login/twitter?................etc"**

Here is my AppDelegate Code for Xamarin.iOS:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate, IAuthenticate
{

        private MobileServiceUser user { get; set; }
    public async Task<bool> Authenticate()
    {
        var res = false;
        if(user == null){
            //var json = new JObject();
            //json.Add("access_token","my token");
            Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            dict.Add("access_token","my token");

            try
            {
                user = await MyManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentedViewController,
                                                                                 MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Twitter,
                                                                                 "my scheme");

                if (user == null)
                {
                    res = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    res = true;
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Login Status: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Login Status: "+res);

        return res;
    }

    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {
        return MyManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.ResumeWithURL(url);
    }


    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {

        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
    //Initializing authenticator
          App.Init(this);

        LoadApplication(new App());
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, false);

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Note that when I change the "Action to take when request is not authenticated" to other than "nothing," it redirects to Facebook authentication (Which surprisingly works this way!!) automatically even if I chose Twitter, but I don't get the result in the app.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error happens after using LoginAsync(): "Cannot GET /.auth/login/twitter?................etc"

Based on your `LoginAsync` method, you are using [server-managed flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow). I would recommend you make sure you have configured the settings correctly on Azure Portal for Twitter provider. You could just browser at `https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/twitter` and find that whether you could get the successful authentication page to narrow this issue. I just created my azure mobile backend and downloaded the quick start sample to check this issue, for your mobile client, just reference the [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/) and followed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users) for adding authentication to your Xamarin Forms app.

Comment: Exactly! I just discoverex after days of struggling that I forgot to add the client secret for Twitter, and the permissions for Facebook(which is not mentioned in the doc).